# knockout.js recursive binding

Tags: binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to do some complex binding with knockout (at least for a newbie like me).

Consider the following data:

```
var originalData = {
id: 1,
name: "Main",
children: [ { id: 2, name: "bob", children: []}, { id: 3, name: "ted", children: [{id: 5, name:"albert"}, {id: 9, name: "fred"}]} ],
selectedChild:  { id: 2, name: "bob" }
};

<table>
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
</tr>
<tr data-bind="if: children().length > 0">
    <td>
        <select data-bind="options: children,
            optionsText: function(item){
                return item.name;
                    }, 
            optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>       
    </td>
</tr>
```

Ok, that was the easy part.

The hard part, is that whenever an item is selected in the list, if this item has children then a new select box should appear underneath. Its datasource would be the children of the selected item in the first select box. Of course, it could continue on with any level of deepness.

How should I solve this problem with knockout ?

I've put together a sample of what I have so far on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/qXZjM/

Comment: one idea that comes to my mind, is to use a template with the same select box inside and append that template to the table element when an item with children is selected. It's not yet clear how I'm going to do it but do you think I'm on the right track ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use recursive templates in knockout by putting the template into a `script` tag. Templates in a `script` tag can reference themselves, like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: 'personTemplate'"></div>

<script type="text/ko" id="personTemplate">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <select data-bind="options: children, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Choose',  value: selectedChild"></select>
    <!-- ko if: selectedChild -->
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'personTemplate', data: selectedChild }"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

**Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/xaBaH/1/)**

---

Update:

You can use a `computed` to easily do this, and remove the logic from the view (which I think is better in this case), and then bind the `if` to it.

```
self.showChildren = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.selectedChild()
        && self.selectedChild().children().length > 0;
});
```

If you want to put both in the `if` block, you can, you just need to include the parens. The reason for this is that observables are functions; knockout lets you exclude them if you are just using the single reference, but they are required to "drill down" to their properties.

```
if: selectedChild() && selectedChild().children().length > 0
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/xaBaH/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that looks awesome ! It's pretty much what I need. Just one thing though, I can't get it to work using the mapping plugin whereas you have used an hard-coded Person function. Could you point me to what I'm doing wrong ? jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/qXZjM/

Comment: actually ignore my comment, it does work now. I just needed to set selectedChild properties to ko.observable(). Thanks a lot !

Comment: one last question: how would you modify the if binding so that the template only shows if there is at least one child for the selectedChild ? I've tried ko if: selectedChild && selectedChild.children.length > 0 but that doesn't work.... Any idea ?

Comment: How would you modify this code to allow the user to add an item at runtime?