# Using Knockout to data-bind hierarchical JSON

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I would like to use Knockout to bind a  structure to hierarchical JSON that is returned from a REST service. in the following form:

```
[{
    Name: "Page 1",
    Children: [ {
        Name: "Page 1 > 1",
        Children: [{
        Name: "Page 1 > 1 > 1",
        Children: []
    }
,{
        Name: "Page 1 > 1 > 2",
        Children: []
    }
]
    }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "Page 2",
    Children: [
    {
        Name: "Page 16",
        Children: []
    }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "Page 3",
    Children: [
    {
        LocalizedName: "aaaaa",
        Children: []
    }
]
```

The standard (foreach) binding only returns the top level. Is there any good way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question addresses the issue of recursive binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531670/knockout-js-recursive-binding

Comment: you can also take a look at this http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html this is on the knockout site it self.